# how to enumerate continuous elements in an array?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

For instance, I have a

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
```

If I call `arr.each`, I will access:

```
1
2
3
4
```

But I want

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Is it possible with built-in function? If not, what's the best practice?

Another question: if I want `1 2` and `3 4`?

Comment: standard advice: read carefully String/Array/Enumerable docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to look at [each_cons](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) for your first case:

```
(1..10).each_cons(3) {|a| p a}
# outputs below
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9, 10]
```

For your second case (wanting sets of elements) you would use [each_slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
(1..10).each_slice(3) {|a| p a}
# outputs below
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[10]
```

Either of these methods accepts a single integer specifying the size of the set, so you would specify `2` instead of `3` (examples are straight from the documentation).